# single sign on for all my struts2 applications in tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2, single-sign-on

I am creating multiple applications using struts2 and deploy it in tomcat7. The users of all the applications are same. So, I decide to authenticate them only once. For this I am using cookies.

Not sure if this is the easiest and best way. but still trying with it.

However, I am unable to achieve it for a single application itself.

Login.jsp

```
<s:form action="login">
<table>
<tr><s:textfield name="username" placeholder="Username"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:password name="userpass" placeholder="Password"></s:password></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr></table> 
</s:form>
```

Login() and Logout()

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public String login() {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con
                .prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) AS rowcount from users where username=? and password=? and its='1'");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, userpass);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        count = rs.getInt("rowcount");
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to login - " + e.getMessage());
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put("login", "true");
        session.put("user", username);

        // Save to cookie
          Cookie user = new Cookie("user", username);
          user.setPath("/");
          servletResponse.addCookie(user);

        return "success";
    } else {
        setError("Invalid login. Try again.");
        return "error";
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public String logout() {
    Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    session.remove("login");
    session.remove("user");
    Cookie user = new Cookie("user", "");
      user.setPath("/");
      servletResponse.addCookie(user);
    return "success";
}
```

LoginCheck.jsp

```
<%
String user = null;
for(Cookie c : request.getCookies()) {
    if (c.getName().equals("user")){
        user = c.getValue();
        }
    }
if(user == null){
    out.println("user : "+user);
    session.setAttribute("login", "false");
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
else{
    out.println("user : "+user);
    session.setAttribute("login", "true");
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    }
%>
```

This code logs me in properly and the cookies are set but even when user is not logged in he home page is getting displayed instead of the login page.

Comment: any example link for this would also help me.

Comment: The place where you check user string... also check the length of user string to be greater than 0 .. inside the logincheck.jsp.. like (user==null || user.length() ==0)

Comment: @SumeetSharma Tried but no use

Comment: Try removing the cooking when you logoff by setting cookie.setMaxAge(0);  //this will remove the cookie at logoff

Comment: I have changed loginCheck.jsp.. as if(user.length() ==0).. it now works but gives an different error.. When I submit the login form, it checks db, create session variables and cookies. but not goes to the home page the browser display the same login page with username filled. After submitting it again it takes to the home page. not clear on what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59920/discussion-between-sumeet-sharma-and-ram).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things you would need to do to solve the above problem

1. set `cookie.setMaxAge(0)` when you logout . This will delete the cookie
   on logout.
2. put a null check on the cookie object. If it exists the user is
   logged in and other applications can use that cookie to login
   directly with the user string in the cookie object

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @SumeetSharma. The working code is

Login() & Logout()

```
public String login() {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con
                .prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) AS rowcount from users where username=? and password=? and its='1'");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, userpass);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        count = rs.getInt("rowcount");
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to login - " + e.getMessage());
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put("login", "true");
        session.put("user", username);
        // Save to cookie
          Cookie user = new Cookie("user", username);
          user.setPath("/");
          servletResponse.addCookie(user);
          return "success";
    } else {
        setError("Invalid login. Try again.");
        return "error";
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public String logout() {
    Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    session.remove("login");
    session.remove("user");
    Cookie user = new Cookie("user", "");
    user.setPath("/");
    user.setMaxAge(0);
      servletResponse.addCookie(user);
    return "success";
}
```

LoginCheck.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%
for(Cookie c : request.getCookies()) {
    if(c==null){
        session.setAttribute("login", "false");
        }
    else if (c.getName().equals("user")){
        session.setAttribute("login", "true");
        session.setAttribute("user", c.getValue());
        }
    }
%>
<s:if test="#session.login != 'true'"> 
<jsp:forward page="login.jsp" />
</s:if>
```